# Centering an element and enlarging it?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, center

If you see my gallery plugin on the right side of this page:

https://kkat.mavenpromedia.com/business-cards/

How can I center the thumbnails and enlargen them slightly?
This is in Wordpress, DIVI theme and the gallery is using a GWTS plugin shortcode.

Thank you!

Comment: You're required to show your code, markup, or CSS here, in your question. Posting a link to a site isn't adequate.

Comment: Judging by all the inline styles on the relevant elements there's a script doing some layout and sizing. If you apply CSS you may break responsive behavior for some situations. Have you checked whether the script has options for those things?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To center them:

```css
ul.lSPager.lSGallery {
  margin: 0 auto !important
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This works for centering, any idea how to enlarge the thumbnails?

Comment: @JenniferT The javascript for this slider sets the width with inline styles so it would be better if you check your slider options before because the css styling can be overwritten from the inline styling. Maybe you can try to set a min-width property for li-elements and see if the javascript from the slider adapts to that. And why somebody dislike my answer when it helped crazy people :D

Comment: Not sure why they thumbed it down, but thanks again for the help!